# Animation with Matplotlin for Bar Graph, Horizontal Graph, etc

Tags: animation, matplotlib

I have a text file that is constantly updating a single value. I'm trying to display this value using matplotlib's animation but I'm having lots of issues. 
For example I want to show a value that's changing every second on the text file (value ranges from 0 to 150) and I want the height of bar graph to increase and decrease with this value.

I want to do the same with horizontal graph. I also want to show a dot moving around the circle for different values (between 0 and 360).

I've tried to many things but it constantly broke the code or matplotlib froze. I've been trying to use matplotlib's animation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should post Your code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36832055/cant-show-animation-for-bar-graph-in-matplotlib I reuploaded the question @TonyBabarino